# Need help in understanding part b of the question - Cylinder and hemisphere

Tags: solid-geometry

[image]

Please, can anyone tell how the answer is 9.5 for part b?

Thank you.

Comment: The total volume of water = the volume of the lower hemisphere + the volume of water in the cylinder with height $h - 6$. Form an expression for total volume of water and equate that equal to $270\pi$ cm$^3$

Comment: Got it thanks..